# Is there any way to use url without writing anything in views?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I have made a model and have registered it.
In the urls i have

Path = (   r'^Api/', )
Is there a way to make this work without adding any views reference?

Comment: Exaclty what do you want to achieve? The Django REST framework has `ViewSet`s that create a lot of views at the same time, and a router to make url entries. But here what would be triggered?

Comment: I just want to handle get and post request without using views, is there any way to do it?

Comment: a view is something that turns a HTTP request in a HTTP response, so basically these are the only "living" things in a web server.

Comment: So a the app wouldn't work without view , no matter what?

Comment: how will you specify what the response should be for a given request?

Comment: it seems that you don't understand what views are exactly in Django, they are not a visual thing, that's what templates are (if coming from another MVC framework, views in Django are like Controllers)